# Display sonata mongodb admin bundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

i'm adding Sonata mongoDB admin Bundle in my project, after doing all the config, it seems that the bundle works fine but there is a problem it does not display the list of the document which is supposed to display.
when i go to /admin i find the sonata admin template but i got it empty. here is my config.yml :

```
sonata_block:
default_contexts: [cms]
blocks:
    # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts:   [admin]



sonata_doctrine_mongo_db_admin:
templates:
    form:
        - SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
    filter:
        - SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
    types:
        list:
            array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
            boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
            date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
            time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
            datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
            text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
            string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

        show:
            array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
            boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
            date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
            time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
            datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
            text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
            trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
            string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
            smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
            bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
            integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
            decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
```

and here is my admin.yml (i followed the documentation) :

```
services:
sonata.admin.question:
    class: ATS\AdminBundle\Admin\questionAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: doctrine_mongodb, group: "Content", label: "Question" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - ATS\QuizzBundle\Document\Question
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ATSAdminBundle]]
```

and finally here is my questionAdmin class (until here i need only to show the list of my questions stored in the db) :

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper; 

class questionAdmin extends Admin
{
// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('question')
    ->add('weight')

        // ->add('tags')
        // ->add('commentsEnabled')

        //add custom action links
    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'actions' => array(
            'view' => array(),
            'edit' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

Any one have the solution plz ? thank you

Comment: Looks fine so far. Where does it not show? On the dashoboard starting page? Are there other admins that do show up? Or do you mean the left menu? Are you sure you have the ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN to see the admins?

Comment: Probably it is not a role problem, in fact the box where i'm supposed to find my model's name, add new and List is not shown

Comment: You could try to see if it works for the left menu. If the role is correct add this to your sonata config: sonata_admin: dashboard: groups: question: items: - sonata.admin.question - https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html#using-the-config-yml